Using Kafka 0.10.2.0 with Scala 2.11 giving java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/common/protocol/SecurityProtocol
I was using Kafka 0.10.2.0 with Scala 2.11 earlier but upgraded scala to 2.12 and now with the same version of kafka when I am running my code its giving the below error
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/common/protocol/SecurityProtocol
I tried to upgrade the kafka version also but its then giving some zkclient errors

`[error]    at kafka.cluster.EndPoint$.<init>(EndPoint.scala:32)
[error]     at kafka.cluster.EndPoint$.<clinit>(EndPoint.scala)
[error]     at kafka.server.Defaults$.<init>(KafkaConfig.scala:63)
[error]     at kafka.server.Defaults$.<clinit>(KafkaConfig.scala)
[error]     at kafka.log.Defaults$.<init>(LogConfig.scala:35)
[error]     at kafka.log.Defaults$.<clinit>(LogConfig.scala)
[error]     at kafka.log.LogConfig$.<init>(LogConfig.scala:208)
[error]     at kafka.log.LogConfig$.<clinit>(LogConfig.scala)
[error]     at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$TopicCommandOptions.<init>(TopicCommand.scala:302)


Kafka is compiled to a specific version of Scala. You cannot only upgrade Scala without installing the corresponding version of Kafka. Also, that version of Kafka is around 5 years old now, so why not upgrade into the 3.x versions and Scala 2.13?
